# Alert when TFS team query definition is modified

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

Is it possible to create a TFS alert that notifies when a work item Team Query definition has been modified?

Not the results of the query, but the actual query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that's not possible.  The Alerts system doesn't support it, and even the advanced option of creating your own ISubscriber plugin ([Event Handling With Subscribers](http://nakedalm.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/)) isn't possible as I don't think there is any Event exposed for changes to WI Queries.

Comment: Oh well. Something to add to UserVoice I guess